# Microsoft Excel getting element in previous row in the adjacent column

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I have a data set in Excel similar to the following:

```
       A        B

1: 07:42:07     2
2: 07:42:08     3
3: 07:42:09     4
4: 07:42:10     5
5: 07:42:11     6
6: 07:42:12     7
7: 07:42:13     8
```

Given a particular time, I would like to extract the value which is diagonal to the specific time. For example, given the value 07:42:10 (at cell A4), I would like to get the value 4 (at cell B3), which is in the previous row and in the next column. I need to be able to pass the time value to the function, so that the respective value in column B will be shown as explained in the example.
Is there a function which will allow me to do this please?

Thank you

Comment: In C2 put `=B1` and fill down.

Comment: That's not the kind of thing I want though. I want a function which I can pass the time to, and it will give me the value that I specified in the question. @Jeeped

Comment: Use index/match

Comment: Could you provide me with an example on how to do this please? @ScottCraner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just offset the range being searched and the result range.

eg:

```
=INDEX(B1:B6,MATCH(G1,A2:A7,0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

`=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$7,MATCH([your time value],$A$1:$A$7,0)-1),"Out of Range")`

Replace `[your time value]` with the value you're looking to match.

I added the `IFERROR` function as the value **07:42:07** would return an error otherwise.

This function will take `[your time value]`, look for an exact match in `$A$1:$A$7`, and return the row number where it is found. We then subtract `1` from the row to get the previous row up (let's call it row ***x***). Now having found our row, we ask the `INDEX` function to return the value from Column B, Row ***x***.